# Android apps - html5 + cocoonjs doesnt work?

Tags: javascript, html, adt, android-virtual-device, cocoonjs

i have a bunch of questions, so i hope you guys will give me a helping hand :)

I got a test app in HTML5 and used ludei/cocoonjs to get adroid app.
I tried to run it on AVD from ADT on Android 2.3/3.0/4.2 and all i got was "Sorry, application suddenly stopped".

So here are my questions:

1. Is there any way to test android apps on PC machine using emulator?
2. Will my app work on mobiles although it doesnt work on emulator? I tested it on my friend mobile and was working fine..
3. What android version is ludei/cocoon compatible with?
4. I want to buy a cheap smartphone to test my application, but im not decided yet, cause i cant runn apps on emulator. Do you think LG Swift L3 (Android 2.3.6) is enough to test C2 + Ludei apps?

Thanks in advance for answers and sorry for my english, im not native speaker/writer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. An .apk generated on the cloud compiler of CocoonJS will not work on the emulator, you need a real device to test an .apk.
2. CocoonJS is compatible with Android 2.3 - 4.x.
3. LG Swift L3 is a very simple device to test a game, my advise is to try with a device with at least 512mb ram.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Actually you *can* get CocoonJS work with Emulator. I had some mailings with Ludei before to track down a JNI bug, here are come excerpts about how to start a compatible emulator. This was a few months ago, and also the version from 2013.07.26 with apk md5sum 55aa7f226b04d698382a604299357094, version 1.3 (although it is advertised to be 1.4).

The key part is the `-gpu on` switch, and optionally switching off JNI checks (for emulators / certain rooted devices):

1. Updated SDK Tools to r21, Platform-tools to r16
2. tools$ ./android create avd -n A15 -t android-15 #(can also make higher platform level emulator)
3. tools$ ./emulator -avd A15 -gpu on
4. platform-tools$ wget http://storage.cocoonjsservice.ludei.com/CocoonJSLauncher.apk
5. (Optional) Remove previous version ./adb uninstall com.ideateca.cocoonjslauncher
6. ./adb install CocoonJSLauncher.apk
7. ./adb logcat
8. Start app on emulator, observe logs

Optionally disable JNI checks to workaround CocoonJS bugs (if starting CocoonJS fails with JNI exception, something like "JNI WARNING: 0x412c40a8 is not a valid JNI reference"):

```
adb shell stop
adb shell setprop dalvik.vm.checkjni false
adb shell start
```

(then emulator/device restarts, after restart JNI checks are not made, source: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html)

By the way, setting `checkjni` to `true` using the above method on a real non-rooted device also causes the problem, if you want to check.

Box2D, Sprite demo, Fonts demo works, didn't check others.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows , perhaps you may find Intel xdk very helpful to run your simulations and the emulators are easy there for android .

speaking of testing the app in native environment , i found phonegap is nice and pretty simple , all you have to do is after uploading your zip file they general for you a .apk file which you can test in real device in any mobile store , you dnt have to buy a mobile to test your app , and if you do HUSTLE to go to nearest mobile shope test it there using scanning QR code from the adobe phonegap build.

And if you dnt want that , there is another platform to test your app via codepen.io it gives a really nice output in different size screen as you needed.

[PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)